# In a virtual reality world, as a programmer or designer, how do you make all the details perfect?

Tags: computers, virtual-reality

Welcome to the world of Sez, the fantastic virtual reality program available for a premium price!

In this world, Sez is very desirable. Sez can make people experience emotions, have memories, and more. However, there's one thing Sez can't really do: the details! That's we at Sez Inc. are rolling out update 3.1!

In a virtual reality experience that wants to look and feel exactly like real life, how do you program in all the details? The knick in the side of a chair, the dent in the cutting board, that one odd crease in your best jacket. With everyone who wants to be part of Sez, the programmers are desperate. **They need a method so that they can account for *everyone's* details of their own personalized, perfect experience.**

Note:
Sez 3.1 has to be *exactly* like real life. No constant bluriness, or living in one-room for the duration of your stay. We need reality!

Comment: Hi Tdonut. Welcome to Worldbuilding SE. Sounds like a nice program, so often seen in culture. Anyway, what do you mean by "details"? Like realistic physical objects, or complete memories, or..? Why would it be hard to get it?

Comment: Hi Tdonut. I'm not completely sure this fits within our scope, but I'm also not sure enough that it doesn't that I am going to close it unilaterally by mod hammer. That said, I edited the title of your question to be more descriptive. Feel free to [edit] further should you feel that is needed.

Comment: Small but essential definition: a definition for "exactly like real life."  If the answers start to trend towards philosophy, we will find that to be an incredibly important detail.  It's like defining the search for extraterrestrial intelligence without defining intelligence.  What you describe pushes against the limits of "qualia," requiring the system to account for how each individual "experiences" sensation at a conscious level.  If we disagree on what that means, the answers become less useful for you.

Comment: This is faaaar too broad. Please refine.

Answer (score 3):

**Have a look on computer graphics** How do we approach it here? Textures. Textures *everywhere*

If you look at your table and feel it by your hands, you will suddenly realize it has one texture everywhere.

You want something more than one texture? Sure! Either give your users dev tools to actually do it, or let them pay for it. The more rustic and old things feel, the more expensive they get.

Cheap areas of your VR will feel brand new. And the more expensive areas will feel rustic, old and have distinctive smell. I just cannot wait for someone to spend bloatloads of money to just create smelly ghetto in your game

Answer (score 1):

Really two answers for two different available technology levels. (Could have just asked, I guess.)

Since Sez can create memories, you can simply feed a memory that the details match, are super-realistic and flawless. When somebody in-game checks the level of detail this overrides the actual result of the check. Human brain is relatively good at filling in the blanks, suberb actually, so this works as long as the person does not think specifically about unsupplied stuff such as the precise texture of a surface. And even then the brain probably will provide suitable false memory of the texture based on some real world texture that the player has encountered that matches. The main issue would be that differnt players would have different memories.

But you could simply openly tell people such trickery is used to enhance experience. There is no actual reason people should care as long as they were told in advance. (Such warning would probably be required by law as messing with memories is quite powerful.) Increased detail is really only useful in that it helps maintain immersion and if you provide such immersion using a memory trick, the actual level of detail is not important.

If Sez is not actually capable of creating memories the key is apparently in textures. (Includes bump maps.) Brain is very good at noticing patterns so, if a texture is small enough to repeat in a single surface or reused in different surfaces, the scene will look less real. There was a game recently (some Lovecraftian stuff, IIRC) that circumvented this by using photographs of real objects as sources for (very large) textures. They had to tone it down in the released game to get fictitional stuff to match, but apparently the result was very realistic.

So large textures based on real objects would be a solution with near current technology. Would take lots of memory though. Algorithmic texture generation is a solution that has been around for decades, but so far it has been simpler to use actual textures, so I don't know if it has been used anywhere. But in theory it could even with current technology provide super-realistic surfaces without requiring huge amounts of RAM. Possible, but not currently available, would be textures based on codecs optimized for compressing larger textures. A game (Rage?) recently kind of did this by using JPEG XR compression on textures and then converting them to something the GPU understands in the game engine. There is no real reason why future GPU could not do this directly.

The two answers can be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

You co-opt the players. They pay you to have their house scanned and the data uploaded to the game. They make an appointment and your scanning team arrives, one "independent franchisee" and a bunch of automated drones. Never mind the fifty pages of fine print, where the customer agrees that those drones will scan his tax receipts and the contents of his hard drive.

Comment: Nobody will trust such a thing, _especially_ if there's a long contract. Smells fishy as hell.

Comment: @Lohoris, most people in the real world don't read website terms of service, and if they do they don't understand them. They're a little bit more attentive when it comes to payments and subscriptions, but not privacy.

Comment: Are you seriously comparing a website TOS with a contract with someone scanning your whole house? Seriously?

Comment: @Lohoris, yes, because I've seen people who really should have known better ignore privacy concerns in the real world. The original question assumed that SEZ is *already* widely popular on the world and merely working on an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this program seems to be able to do full input/output with human experience, you can data-mine from people's own memories. An awful lot of detail is noted by the brain but never consciously used, and if your program can perform data IO from any part in the brain then you can retrieve much of that data. Even better for your programmers, people tend to thing of objects in conceptual terms, so the thought ' this is a kettle' will automatically start to bring back information associated with the word 'kettle'

Where this could get tricky is integration. Memory is imperfect, but that doesn't really matter if you've only got one person: what they remember is what they expect reality to be like anyway. When you've got more than one person overlapping areas of memory might need careful integration to accurately map them together. Employing 'bugtesters' to go through such areas and make them seem 'more real' by eliminating merge-artefacts and replacing them with things that feel more authentic (even if they aren't). Using this method you can make Sez 3.1 not just real, but *more* than real.

Of course, people might object to you downloading the entirety of their conscious/subconscious experience and exploiting it. But those people can be safely ignored in the name of progress.

Oh, and watch out for people who have experienced bad drug trips. Maaaaaajor bug-territory there. Literally. There'll be spiders in the walls...

Answer (score 0):

IF this virtual reality works by transmitting straight to the brain (and since you claim to stimulate ALL senses, I assume this is true), just use that highway to collect information. IF you can send information, you should also be able to receive it. Simply use the consumer's memories to "patch" your reality. Most of this will probably be by simply pasting a small texture on something, but in some cases you can even use this information to build entirely new rooms or buildings. This patch would take a while to completely work, since it will need constant motoring so nothing inappropriate comes through, but otherwise it is the most effective technique you can use.